# Why does program open in task manager only, and not onscreen

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, process

I have the following batch file which does two things;

1. Confirms the program is running, if not it opens the program.
2. Confirms the program is running, if it is the batch file does nothing.

I created this batch file to ensure the program is always open, I have a scheduled task to do this check every 5 minutes.

The problem I have is if i manually double click on the batch file, the program opens onscreen. However, when the schedule task executes, it starts the process in the task manager, and not onscreen.

This is the content of the batch file;

```
@echo off
set tempfile=bdw.txt

del %tempfile%
tasklist > %tempfile%

GOTO NOTRUNNING


:NOTRUNNING
type %tempfile% | find /i "chrome.exe"
if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 goto END
goto START

:START
del %tempfile%
start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
exit

:END
del %tempfile%
exit
```

Any idea why it would do this?

Comment: Scheduled tasks run on a non-interactive desktop by default. see https://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-7/windows-7-run-scheduled-task-interactively/

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in relation to the user groups assigned to the scheduled task. Using the link provided by FloatingKiwi, I changed the task security options to "users" and this corrected the problem. Now the program opens onscreen.